# ERROR TypeError: res.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've a `HTML` code which is as given below.

```
<div *ngIf="chart" class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6">
      <div class="card cardColor mb-3">
        <div class="card-header headColor">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="../../../assets/images/chart-bars-box-16-white.png" /> &nbsp;
          <b>Issue Chart</b>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <canvas id="canvas">{{ chart }}</canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I've an API from where I'm pulling data.

```
url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dnpid';
```

This is code for line graph:

```
// line graph
        this.httpClient.get(this.url).subscribe((res: Data[]) => {
            res.forEach(y => {
              this.year.push(y.year);
              this.price.push(y.price);
            });
            this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
              type: 'line',
              data: {
                labels: this.year,
                datasets: [
                  {
                    data: this.price,
                    borderColor: '#6ea204',
                    fill: false
                  }
                ]
              },
              options: {
                legend: {
                  display: false
                },
                scales: {
                  xAxes: [{
                    display: true
                  }],
                  yAxes: [{
                    display: true
                  }],
                }
              }
            });
          });
```

There is an interface to manage the data:

```
export interface Data {
    year: String;
    price: number;
}
```

Whenever I run this in a browser, I get error below:

> ```
> ERROR TypeError: res.forEach is not a function
>   at SafeSubscriber._next (dashboard.component.ts:130)
> ```

What could be the problem?

Comment: it should be ```res.results.foreach```

Comment: What is the value of `res`. Put a check `Array.isArray(res)` before doing a `.forEach()`

Comment: @SachinGupta: Value of `res` is `{results: Array(5)}
results: Array(5)
0: {year: "2015", price: "978"}
1: {year: "2016", price: "657"}
2: {year: "2017", price: "989"}
3: {year: "2018", price: "1045"}
4: {year: "2019", price: "300"}
length: 5`

Comment: @AjayKulkarni so, it's an object, not an array. It has *in it* an array, though.

Comment: So it has to be `object.key.forEach`?

Comment: I removed that `key`. It is a simple `json` now. https://api.myjson.com/bins/105lid. But I'm gettng same error...

Comment: Try ```Array.prototype.forEach.call(res.results, y=> {
  console.log(y)
});```

Comment: @AjayKulkarni after you've changed it there are no arrays at all. All you have is a single object. I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Félix said objects themselves do not have a foreach method, but you can iterate upon the object if it is iterable or Array-like like this

```
Array.from(res).forEach
```

Comment: Not working.. Getting this error. `error TS2339: Property 'from' does not exist on type 'Data[]'.
 error TS2304: Cannot find name 'results'.`

Comment: @AjayKulkarni I changed the answer, should work now,

Comment: I don't know about charts, try debugging to see if it is receiving the information

Answer (score 4):

You are receiving this error because objects themselves do not have a `foreach` method, rather, arrays do.

Your API returns an object with a `results` key, most likely being the array you would like to iterate upon.

I believe you want to use `res.results.forEach` instead.